# How could I restart a google compute engine instance hung since sundays june 2nd incident?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The instance status indicates a revolving arrow and the only option I have is deleting the instance. Is there a way to stop or restart it without deleting it and losing everything. It started when I was trying to stop it from the console during the outage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can save the disk creating a snapshot and then use it to create a new instance. Follow [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) to create the snapshot and [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) to create a new instance from it.

Comment: Alternatively, in order to stop these instances, for each one of the affected instance you should run the following command in the Cloud Shell:   

$ gcloud compute instances stop <instance-name> --zone=<zone-name>

Answer (score 0):

You can check status of Google Cloud, keep track of incidents or/and get reports and recommendations at [Google Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/). I assume that your issue related to [Google Compute Engine Incident #19003](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/compute/19003).

Accordingly to the documentation [Creating persistent disk snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) "you can create snapshots from disks even while they are attached to running instances". After that, you'll be able to create a new VM instance by following the documentation [Creating a VM instance from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot).

To keep your data protected, I'd recommend you to [create snapshots on schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots).

In case, if you're facing any issues you can file an [issue report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#issue_reports) at [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).